# GET-запрос дёргает страницу вверх

Tags: php, javascript, get

Доброго всем.
Вот возникла необходимость приписать суффикс к JS функции, через PHP посредством GET.
Исходник работает отлично.

```
<div id="button" onClick="dark_view('on')">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showBlock_03()" style="красатульки"><span style="текстовые-красатульки">КНОПКА</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

---

А передать хочу сюда:

```
<?php print "<div style='красатульки' onClick='showBlock_[здесь хочу suffix]();'>Кнопка закрыть</div>"; ?>
```

Но стоит заменить javascript:void(0) на ?sufix=03, так сразу страница прыгает вверх и вся моя форма, открытая посредством JS, закрывается.
Т.е. Get сбрасывает работу скриптов JS.
Как это можно обойти?

Comment: style="красатульки" -- вот это убило наповал...

Answer (score 1):

В функции show_block_03() укажите в конце

```
return false;
```

Или просто

```
 <a href="your_link" onclick="showblock_03(); return false;">press me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если используется jquery, то сначала принимаем параметр event в функции, а в самой функции
event.preventDefault()